# Share company-wide gitignore file

Tags: git, gitignore

Our company maintains several software projects, all versioncontrolled in different git repositories. All projects already have .gitignore files.

Question: How can I establish one single shared .gitignore file accross all company projects?

Add-on question: The file should be readonly to most people I guess. Otherwise we would run into uncontrolled changes.

Edit: What about "deploying" the .gitignore file using a custom NuGet package? Do you think this is a practical approach? It would be a pull principle and rather hard to enforce it in all projects.

Comment: How many different repos do you have?

Comment: I don't think there is a "built-in" way to accomplish this. What you are thinking of is some sort of import of rules form one `gitignore` file to another. Unfortunately, there is no such concept. If all your projects have sort of an "init script" (one that precreates runtime folders, DB, etc), you could integrate in it the logic to pull the centralized `gitignore` file contents and append it to the project's `gitignore`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: There are about 10-15 actively maintained repositories.

Comment: I'd suggest to run a server side hook like `pre-receive` to decline any push that includes new commit(s) with specific file suffixes. Let the project maintainers to care about .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in way to do what you want. You get to figure out how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your to your `.gitconfig` in your home directory.

```
[core]
  excludesFile = path/to/some/central/gitignore_global`
```

Not sure if it works for a `gitignore_global` on a network share, but I don't see any reason it wouldn't.